# Linux stuck at boot: A start job is running for

Tags: linux, boot, systemd, nixos

I have a NixOS server that got stuck at boot after I rebooted it. It's displaying the following message: `A start job is running for Waiting for NixOps keys (1d 3h / no limit)`

That job that the system is waiting for is a systemd service. I did some research I and I found that when this issue occurs, it usually times out after a certain time and the system boots. However, in my case it's been stuck for over a day. Any ideas how to bypass that state?

Comment: In the link you posted, the OS boots after 1min30s of waiting. My issue is different: the boot is stuck with "no limit" timeout and I need a way to get into the system.

Answer (score 1):

According to the NixOps manual...

> Keys from deployment.keys are stored under /run/ on a temporary
>   filesystem and will not persist across a reboot...Note that all nixops commands implicitly upload keys when appropriate, so manually sending keys should only be necessary after an unattended reboot.

Try the `nixops send-keys` command.

```
nixops send-keys [ --include machine-name... ] [ --exclude machine-name... ]
Description

This command uploads the keys described in deployment.keys to remote machines in the /run/keys/ directory.

Keys are not persisted across reboots by default. If a machine reboot is triggered from outside nixops, it will need nixops send-keys to repopulate its keys.

Note that nixops deploy does an implicit send-keys where appropriate, so manually sending keys is only necessary after unattended reboots.
Options

--include machine-name...

    Only operate on the machines explicitly mentioned here, excluding other machines.
--exclude machine-name...

    Only operate on the machines that are not mentioned here.
```

See https://nixos.org/nixops/manual/#idm140737318306400

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. For nixops to work, the server has to be reachable over the network. In my case, it's not even booting and networking is not up yet.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I misunderstood. I think of "booting" as when the bootloader loads the Linux kernel and kicks it off. You're getting a message about NixOps, so the kernel is definitely loaded. Take a look at the following link. It contains options you can give to the kernel and systemd. It should allow you to stop log in early during stage1, before services are started: https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-boot-problems